# Date Changing Interval

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

Not much coding experience, but hoping the community can help. I'd like to have a simple HTML headline read the following:

**"Meals are available for pickup on Sunday,February 23 and Monday, February 24."**

The crux is I need this to change every Thursday at 1 p.m. so that the dates change to the dates of the FOLLOWING Sunday & Monday.

--

We are a meal prep service with new menus every week. Order cut off is every Thursday @ 1 p.m. I've automated the site's meal menu to rotate at this time. With this dynamic headline, I hope to avoid customer confusion so that if someone orders on Thursday @ 2 p.m., they know their meals aren't going to be available until the following weekend.

Hope that makes sense. Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this quite easily using the php [time](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.time.php) functions

Example:

```php
<?php
$monday_date = strtotime('next monday');
$sunday_date = strtotime('next sunday');
?>
<!-- Some content -->
<div class="header">Meals are available for pickup on Sunday,February $sunday_date and Monday, February $monday_date</div>
<!-- Some more content -->
```

The above example wont rotate at 1pm but will show the date of the closest sunday/monday. I leave it as an exercise to the reader to work out how to adapt it for timings (hint: the `time` library can detect the current time)

Comment: Thanks for the example! 

Correct me if I'm wrong, but if it's finding the closest Sunday/Monday, this wouldn't work. If a user ordered on Friday, the closest Sunday/Monday would be incorrect. It would need to be 7 days from those two.

Comment: You can add 7 days to the date. Look at the DateTime class.

Comment: You can also have some code to check if it is friday with (strtotime('F')) and then logic statements from there